# Has anyone been successful porting Prex to a Stellaris chip?

Tags: embedded, arm

Has anyone been successful porting the Prex OS ([prex.sf.net](http://prex.sf.net)) to a Stellaris chip?  I am interested in verifying that Prex can be embedded on smaller memory footprint systems.  If someone has already done the work and is willing to share that would be great.

Comment: If you are looking for a stellaris chip and an rtos, why not consider the TI Stellaris chips that come with SafeRTOS already onboard in ROM?

Comment: I have a few stellaris boards (from TI, well at the time luminary micro) already.  It is prex I am interested in not Free/Open/SafeRTOS.  Not a fan of OSes anyway, prex so far is the only one I found interesting.  I had looked at those though, and a number of others.

Comment: thanks for the comment though Warren. There has been some recent activity in the Prex forums, kinda waiting for it to find a direction and home.

Answer (score 4):

[Your link](http://prex.sourceforge.net/) explicitly says the requirements are:

- Processor: 32-bit Processor (x86, ARM, PowerPC)
- Memory: 256KB of RAM (Kernel < 25k bytes)
- Timer: programmable interval timer

Since the kernel is under 25 KB, I would guess it will probably just work; [this stellaris page](http://www.luminarymicro.com/products/products.html) says the chip has 96 KB of SRAM.  Depending on your application requirements, you should be off to the races.  What specific problems are you having?

Comment: Problems, understanding the build/configuration options.  A tiny footprint example would have been good, and cortex-m3 has its own startup and thumb requirements